# How to handle versions of sbt, scala, libraries

Tags: scala, sbt, version

When playing with something in Scala, I typically spend a bunch of time trying combinations of dependency versions, Scala versions, `%%` vs `%`, etc. And when it starts working, I am not quite sure why, or for how long...

It would be great if someone could explain the Scala ecosystem's way(s) of dealing with versions of sbt, scala, and libraries. Or perhaps point me to some documentation.

Comment: To clarify, `%%` is used when you need an artifact corresponding to your `scalaVersion`. For example, `"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "latest.release"` is equivalent to `"com.typesafe.scala-logging" % "scala-logging_2.11" % "latest.release"` if `scalaVersion` is `2.11`.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who downvotes without even posting a link... Part of the problem I guess.

Comment: Agreed with @mitchus. Dependency management when first coming to scala is daunting and certainly not well explained. I'd consider it one of the barriers of entry to the eco-system. I'm sure there are better explanations than my attempt and its sad to see no one stepping up.

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this extensively when i started out. These days i start every project with a boiler-plate `build.sbt` with just scalaVersion and whatever sbt is currently on my machine:

```
organization := "foo"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

Pick the latest 2.10 or 2.11, dependening on your need. Most libraries of note are cross-published into both.

Now, as you find libraries you want to use, head over to http://mvnrepository.com/ and search for them there. Look for a *_2.10* or *_2.11* postfix (depending on your version). If it has neither, you are likely fine.

Once you find your library and the version you want, mavenrepository even provides you the sbt link you need to use in its *sbt* tab like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play-test_2.10" % "2.4.0-M3"
```

And from there you can even explore the dependencies that library will bring along with it. This should cover most of your day to day needs.

Comment: Note that using scala version explicitly is not really idiomatic and may make porting your program to different scala versions unnecessarily harder. You should write `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-test" % "2.4.0-M3"` in order for SBT to add scala version suffix to the artifact name automatically.

Comment: I tried idiomatic originally and just had so many problems with getting sbt to do proper resolution that i just gave up and went with specifying the postfix to get things working. Not sure what i was doing wrong then, but this has worked best for me.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev thanks for the feedback. If you have some more info on idiomatic versioning, please make it into a separate answer.